# How to make wp to compare meta value from associated array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, meta-query

I have used Wordpress meta query with LIKE operator But it displays below kind of characters in my query when I am trying to debug issue:

Actual Code (in file): LIKE

```
{5b6ec0a79eca15c692a3a0de9762a0e6971f54fde940b4477844716b99b4cfb5}\'\\{5b6ec0a79eca15c692a3a0de9762a0e6971f54fde940b4477844716b99b4cfb5}:\"419\";\\{5b6ec0a79eca15c692a3a0de9762a0e6971f54fde940b4477844716b99b4cfb5}\'{5b6ec0a79eca15c692a3a0de9762a0e6971f54fde940b4477844716b99b4cfb5}'
```

Due to these unwanted characters my query is not executing properly, if I use below code in my query with database directly it runs perfectly:

```
Correction code(in phpmyadmin execution): LIKE `%:\"419\";%
```

fFor this, we use the wp meta query. In this comparison, I am storing associated array value in **confirmed_artist_ids** meta key

```
$meta_query_projects[] = array(
                                'key' => 'confirmed_artists_ids',
                                'value' => sprintf('%:"%s";%', $current_id),
                                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$meta_query_projects[] = array(
                                'key' => 'confirmed_artists_ids',
                                'value' => $current_id,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                            );
```

**can you try this code**